# Codeigniter does not recognize css, js file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeIgniter. I'm using latest version of codeigniter. I have an HTML template that I'm trying to convert it codeIgniter.

However, I have created

- header_view.php
- navigation_view.php
- content_view.php
- footer_view.php

Under application/views folder. I have copied all CSS, js, image folder under views.

So, now my problem is that stylesheet not working. Can you give me some instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Your css, images, java script etc **should be located out side of the application folder** not in the views

- application
- assets
- assets > css
- assets > images
- assets > js
- index.php
- .htaccess

The [url helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) should be autoload also.

Then you will be able to use in head area

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/yourstylesheet.css');?>">

<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/yourjs.js');?>"></script>
```

> Note: When posting a question on stack overflow would all ways be best
>   to include some code where your problem is. Also all ways good to read [CodeIgniter Docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/docs) and codeIgniter forum is here http://forum.codeigniter.com/

And you may need to create a htaccess file for main directory

Here  is an example htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: After adding this .htaccess file , I got server error warning.

Comment: @Jhon try more htaccess here `https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter` you may need to remove index.php in config.php

Answer (score 0):

After using the url helper like @wolfgang rightly said.

Please do not forget to check your .htaccess file at the root of your project and add this if it's not specified

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
```

Every new folder you want to add to CI that needs to be read by your code as an external folder must be specified. If you want to add another folder just add and extra pipe and add the folder name. For example.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|mynewfolder|robots\.txt)
```

Hope this helps.